# Applying Script Library for Timeline

Tags: google-app-maker

This is a follow up to my previous question. I apologize if this is too complex to answer here.

I am trying to be able to show my data in a timeline view. I found a timeline script from Google here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

But I'm not sure I am doing this correctly. I'm assuming I am supposed to:

Add https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js under the Settings section of my app.

Then am I inserting this code as a client script?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

If so, I'm confused as I am getting an error: drawChart was used before it was defined.

I was then HOPING I would swap out 'Washington' for @datasources.item.FieldName and the dates for @datasources.item.StartDate and @datasources.item.EndDate.

But maybe I am totally misunderstanding how this could actually work.

Also to actually show the table would I be using an HTML widget?

Thank you for any help anyone could offer.

Answer (score 3):

You have many questions in one post, I will only answer the first one.
It should be trivial to show your own data from a model object.

First the result: :-)

[image]

Steps:

1. In App Settings, under External Resources, add JavaScript URL: `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`
2. The client script should look like this:

   ```
   function showChart(widget){
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
       function drawChart() {
          var container = widget.getElement();
          var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
          var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
          dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
          dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
          dataTable.addRows([
             [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
             [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
         chart.draw(dataTable);
       }
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   }
   ```

Note that Google uses non-standard Javascript, where it is required that methods be declared before they are used, so the `setOnLoadCallback` must take place after the declaration of `drawChart`. Also note the use of `widget.getElement()` to get a DOM object from an App Maker widget.

3. Add an HTML widget to a page, give it the desired width and height, and on its `onAttach` event, add a call to `showChart(widget);`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the help!