# How to list separate parts of a date entry

Tags: google-app-maker

So the short version of the question, is there a way to display only a certain portion of a Date field entry in a model?

ex: I enter 02/13/2017 as an entry, but on a separate page I only want to see the day, or month or year? Not the whole thing.

Longer explanation.

I am using the following code in conjuncture with a [Google charts script](https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js) ([see previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170805/applying-script-library-for-timeline)) to make a Timeline:

```
function showChart(widget){
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
    function drawChart() {
       var container = widget.getElement();
       var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
       var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
       dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
      chart.draw(dataTable);
    }
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
}
```

If I add/define a variable I can replace the labels for the rows with data from my model. Example: RoomName

```
function showChart(widget){
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
        function drawChart() {
           var container = widget.getElement();
           var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
           var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
           var RoomName = app.datasources.TestModel.item.RoomName;
           dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
           dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
           dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
           dataTable.addRows([
              [ 'RoomName', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
              [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
              [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
          chart.draw(dataTable);
        }
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    }
```

I would like to do the same with the Check In and Check Out dates, however the new Date option has the Year, Month and Day separated into 3 variables (example above: **new Date(1789, 3, 30)**. So I can't just use app.datasources.TestModel.item.CheckIn.

Is there a way I can tell App make to app.datasources.TestModel.item.CheckIn (year), app.datasources.TestModel.item.CheckIn (month), app.datasources.TestModel.item.CheckIn (day)?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you are using bindings, I'll suggest using date transformer  https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/transformers#formatDate, in case you are setting values using script... you can try to add 3rd property to your column description - pattern (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn)

Answer (score 1):

If you store dates in your model, you can split the date into its components using Javascript, with `date.getYear()+1900`, `date.getMonth()+1`and `date.getDate()`

But there is no reason to do so, the dates accepted by the chart API are regular dates, just because they are shown in a particular format does not mean you have to do the same.

```
dataTable.addRows([
              [ 'RoomName', startDate, endDate ],
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` come from your model works just as well

Comment: One more question: For the startDate and endDate options, is there a way I can filter them so they are displaying startDate for Room1, then startDate for Room2, etc? I was originally going to create a new datasource and use a query to filter the RoomName, but then I realized that won't work because then the datasource for the startDate/endDate is then different than the HTML widget. Does that make sense?